# Want to access static resource using CAMEL, CXF and Karaf

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-camel, apache-karaf

I am new to CAMEL, CXF and Karaf.
I want to access static file using CAMEL with CXF and KARAF.
Wanted to know the best way to do that.
I have searched through net and found that CXF based rest web service can be written for the same.
Is there any other simpler way for this.
We are using jboss FUSE server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got a better way to do the same.

1. **Step 1**
   Add <_wab>src/main/webapp/ tag in you maven pluggin so that your bundle can be treated as WAB by karaf container.

   Use  and  to declare your custom context path.
   By default maven will take Bundle-SymbolicName as context.
2. **Step 2.**
   Write web.xml. Place it under /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.
3. **Step 3.**
   Place your static resource file under webapp folder.
4. **Step 4.**
   Build the code to generate bundle jar using maven command mvn clean install and deploy the jar in karaf
5. **Step 5** 
   Use below link to access the static resource.
   http://:8181//

Answer (score 2):

To solve this problem we can define a redirect-list which will contain pattern of static resources you want to serve and the CRX default servlet will take care of forwarding to the specific resource please refer the following url for more information

[Redirecting requests and serving the static content](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/servlet-transport.html)

[web.xml file which does what is described above](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/systests/jaxrs/src/test/resources/jaxrs_dispatch/WEB-INF/web.xml)