# trying to deploy web page to karaf as a web application using cxf

Tags: web-services, servlets, cxf, apache-karaf, karaf

I am trying to deploy a web app into karaf service mix using the steps from this post : [Want to access static resource using CAMEL, CXF and Karaf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25446997/want-to-access-static-resource-using-camel-cxf-and-karaf)

I have not had any luck yet getting my web page to work after deploy to karaf
I have a few questions. I have just one index.html and on js file and just trying to get something working. I am trying to get my web.xml set up and not sure I need any mappings or anything else. here is my web.xml. Any other tips for getting this to work or a good very simple example just to get something working.Thanks!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">
<web-app>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>config-location</param-name>
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>    
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>static-welcome-file</param-name>
      <param-value>/index.html</param-value>
   </init-param> 
   <init-param>
      <param-name>static-resources-list</param-name>
      <param-value>/index.html</param-value>
   </init-param> 
   <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Comment: I am the poster of this question. I am still confused if I need to impement any Java code ?  maybe to implement the servlet?? Right now I just have  my web page html/.js and web.xml and my pom and my congiguration  file :